# Arduino Issue: Using TimerOne and delayMicroseconds()

Tags: c, timer, arduino

I have been working with an Arduino and have encountered a very strange problem. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

const int LED_PIN = 8;

const int PERIOD = 3000; // micros

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

  Timer1.initialize(PERIOD);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(sendPulse);

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{

}

void sendPulse()
{
  Serial.println(micros());
  delayMicroseconds(x);
  Serial.println();
}
```

So, I have tried changing the value of x in sendPulse(). If x is 300, for example, the Serial monitor outputs "3016 6016 9016...," as expected. However, something strange occurs when x is greater than or equal to 835 -- the Serial monitor outputs "3016 4992 7992...." My question is why is the time between the first and second interrupt not 3000? Furthermore, if I change the code within the interrupt to:

```
  Serial.println(micros());
  delayMicroseconds(x);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  Serial.println();
```

The code acts strangely for x greater than or equal to 830, rather than 835. Why does this happen? Thank you!

Comment: One can't tell for sure without knowing how the arduino library implements things under the hood. But you're not supposed to delay or run a big job inside a interrupt service routine. Set some flags and return ASAP. Otherwise, new interrupt events might be lost, as you cannot have a interrupt inside a interrupt on AVR, throwing things in disarray. The fact that adding a call to `digitalwrite` lowers your maximum delay time seems to agree with this view.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/how-do-interrupts-work-on-the-arduino-uno-and-similar-boards):

1. you shouldn't use `Serial.print()/Serial.read()` in an *interrupt service routine*, because latest version of `Serial` uses *interrupts* for *read and write* but they are disabled from within an *ISR*.
2. you shouldn't use`delay()/delayMicroseconds()`, because again they make use of *interrupts* but they are disabled from within an *ISR*.. your risk making the *timer* miss some *interrupts* and loose track of the correct *flow of time*.

---

As a remark I repeat here what was said by @Unimportant in the comments: *the code within an ISR should be kept as short and fast as possible.*